# Syntax Error; Python game spits out super method and imports

Tags: python, import, pygame, syntax-error, super

I made classes for what will basically become a BreakOut game, but I keep getting error messages. The nature of which always seem to surround two things; Class imports and the infamous "super" method. Usually in the form of a syntax error

I had some questions shot down in the past, so I will try to be as clear as I possibly can.

The main code for the game is as such...

```
 import pygame

 from Game import *
 from Game.Scenes import *
 from Game.Shared import *


 class BreakOut:

def __init__(self):
    self.__lives = 5
    self.__score = 0

    self.__level = Level(self)
    self.__level.load(0)

    self.__pad = Pad((0,0), 0)
    self.__balls = [Ball((0,0), 0, self)]

    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("This is the Title of the Game")

    self.__clock= pygame.time.Clock()

    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(GameConstants.SCREEN_SIZE, pygame.DOUBLEBUF, 32)

    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

    self.__scenes = (
        PlayingGameScene(self),
        GameOver(self),
        HighScoreScene(self),
        MenuScene(self)
    )

    self.__currentScene = 0

    self.__sounds = ()


def start(self):
    while 1:
        self.__clock.tick(100)


        self.screen.fill((0,0,0))

        currentScene = self.__scenes[self.__currentScene]
        currentScene.handleEvents(pygame.event.get())
        currentScene.render()

        pygame.display.update()
def changeScene(self, scene):
    pass

def getLevel(self):
    pass

def getScore(self):
    pass

def increaseScore(self, score):
    pass

def getLives(self):
    pass

def getBalls(self):
    pass


def getPad(self):
    pass

def playSound(self, soundClip):
    pass

def reduceLives(self):
    pass

def increaseLives(self):
    pass

def reset (self):
    pass


BreakOut().start()
```

At this stage, its only supposed to return a black screen, but instead it keeps giving me a error message with this traceback:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Ryan/PycharmProjects/Demo 1/Game/BreakOut.py", line 3, in <module>
  from Game import *
File "/Users/Ryan/PycharmProjects/Demo 1/Game/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  from Game.BreakOut import BreakOut
File "/Users/Ryan/PycharmProjects/Demo 1/Game/BreakOut.py", line 4, in <module>
  from Game.Scenes import *
File "/Users/Ryan/PycharmProjects/Demo 1/Game/Scenes/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  from Game.Scenes.HighScoreScene import HighScoreScene
File "/Users/Ryan/PycharmProjects/Demo 1/Game/Scenes/HighScoreScene.py", line 7

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The bottom one connects to another class of code that looks like this:

```
from Game.Scenes.Scene import Scene

class HighScoreScene(Scene):

    def __init__(self, game):
        super(HighScoreScene, self.__init__(game)
```

PyCharm seems to highlight "super" and tells me "Old-style class contains call for super method" I don't know if that's important or not, but its something I've noticed consistently throughout the code.

I'm pretty sure its a simple mistake. Might be a typo, but I can't pinpoint it for the life of me. Please help!

Comment: Also, if you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: I have solved the Problem. Thank You for all you help and have a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 super(HighScoreScene, self.__init__(game) # <- missing  paren
```

It should be `super(HighScoreScene, self).__init__(game)`

And use `object` `class BreakOut(object)` if you want to use `super`.

[New-style and classic classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes)

Comment: Wow Thanks didn't see that. That at least fixes the last line on the Traceback, but I'm still getting errors

Comment: TypeError:must be type, not classobj

Comment: I think the new error lies in another line of code. I will be posting that in a new question. Thank You for your help!

Comment: Yeah I applied your advice about the object code and super to the classes that were being referred too. That was the problem; using old style classes for new style super. Thank you so much and have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

Your `class Breakout` line is not in line with the rest of your program (ahead by one space). If you backspace that line by one, everything should be fine (including @Padraic Cunningham 's answer).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately I think that's more of a copy/paste error then one I actually coded. I just spaced them unevenly. Sorry